# Access this of a controller when using controller as inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, controlleras

How do i access `This` of controller inside of directive and its template when not using isoloted scope?

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function() {
  this.name = "Name from children";
});
```

Comment: by adding `controller:'ChildCtrl as ctrl'` in directive

Comment: Like scope it does not get shared with directive?

Comment: there really isn't enough in the question to explain the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple parse it as `controller as instance value` into your directive scope like in this **[simple fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v3cvre5a/)**:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  Hello, <span simple-directive data="ctrl.name"></span>!
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.name = 'Superhero';
});

myApp.directive('simpleDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '{{ data }}',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.data);
    }
  }
});
```

---

An other approach is to just parse your controller into the directive by using `controller:'MyCtrl as ctrl'` like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q62u63j8/1/)**.

#### View

```
Hello, <span simple-directive></span>!
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  this.name = 'Superhero';
});

myApp.directive('simpleDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller:'MyCtrl as ctrl',
    template: '{{ ctrl.name }}'
  }
});
```

---

You can also parse the hole controller instance to in scope and access it  like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3dwcb3y/1/)**.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  Hello, <span simple-directive ctrl="ctrl"></span>!
  <br />
  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name">
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.name = 'Superhero';
});

myApp.directive('simpleDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ctrl: '='
    },
    template: '{{ ctrl.name }}',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    }
  }
});
```